# Split a string into its predefined components in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string:

`!fun(10,20)`

I am trying to split it into the following component parts:

`!`, `fun`, `10`, `20`

The `!` is always the first character. The `fun` is always the next 3 chars after the `!`, the `10` will always follow an open bracket `(`, the `20` will be always follow the first comma `,` before the close bracket.

I’ve tried using PHP functions but have been banging my head against a wall. I am presuming I can do this using a regular expression or similar.

Comment: maybe you need regExp, what string you want to split?

Comment: Are you saying that the strings always start with the characters "!fun(" and end with ")"? If these never vary then it's probably fastest just to split the string using strstr and explode, otherwise you could use a regex like /^!fun\((\d+.\d+)\)$/ but it depends on exactly what you're asking

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the fun will change, the ! is always !, the fun can be any 3 letters, the 10 and 20 can be any int.

Comment: Many possibilities... [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf), regular expressions, `substr`... depends on how variable the parts are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/^!(\w{3})\((\d+),(\d+)\)$/', $string, $matches);
```

Then `$matches` will contain:

```
matches: Array
(
    [0] => !fun(10,20)
    [1] => fun
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 20
)
```

I'm no expert with regex, feel free to comment if it can be reduced.

Comment: I'd suggest '/^!(\w{3})\((\d+),(\d+)\)$/' to limit to three characters for the function name. You don't need the [] either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=!fun(10,20);
$arr=array('!','(',')',',');
$string=str_replace($arr,'_',$string);
$exp_string=explode('_',$string);
print_r($exp_string);
```

You can find more at http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '#\!([a-zA-Z]+)\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)#s';
```